# how to cancel the "start" request using "stop" request in flask?

Tags: python, flask

when clicked on the "start" button on the Web UI, the program plans to process the data using threading.Timer() with 0.01s frequency within 5000 steps. A “stop” button is offered to stop processing_data() at any time and return a part of the result being computed during the time.

```
step = 0
result = {}
thread = None

@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def start():
    processing_data()
    time.sleep(5000*0.01) # wait for the processing_data() finished
    return Response(result, mimetype='application/json')

def processing_data():
    result = {json : format} # compute the json format result
    if step != 5000:
        global step
        step +=1
        global thread
        thread = threading.Timer(0.01, processing_data)
        thread.start()

@app.route('/stop', methods=['GET'])
def stop():
    thread.cancel()
    return "stopped"
```

It doesn't work, seems like the stop() will only run after the start() is finished. So my question is how to cancel the start() request during the processing? Suppose the user is impatient, who simply want to get a part of the computed result after certain steps?

EDIT:
I tried to further simplified the program, removed the thread, add the application context of Flask. It's all the same, it means the thread is not the problem, a request or the sleep() can simply not be interrupted.

```
step = 0
result = {}

@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def start():
    g.__stop = False
    processing_data()
    time.sleep(5000*0.01) # wait for the processing_data() finished
    return Response(result, mimetype='application/json')

def processing_data():
    result = {json : format} # compute the json format result
    if step != 5000 and not g.__stop:
        global step
        step +=1
        processing_data()

@app.route('/stop', methods=['GET'])
def stop():
    g.__stop = True
    return "stopped"
```

Comment: um... you are trying to modify the global `step` variable without declaring it as global. so it isn't actually changing the global `step` at all and this will create an infinite series of Threads (same for `result`)

Comment: sorry, I just have simplified my program, so there is maybe bugs, maybe the global thread is bad idea, I will fix it later. Now I just wonder, is it possible at all to cancel a thread like this way in the Flask?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it is not a good idea. You'll usually have this process running behind something like WSGI. In this instance, you'll have multiple processes. When you request /stop, there's no way to know you've stopped it, since that thread might exist on a difference process than the one that is handling your request. You should use something like Celery to do this.